# Parse Approved-By from git log or git show

Tags: json, git, git-log

Using `--pretty=format`, you can format `git log` or `git show` stdout as you like.

```
git log \
--pretty=format:'{%n  "commit": "%H",%n  "author": "%an <%ae>",%n  "date": "%ad",%n  "message": "%f"%n},' \
$@ | \
perl -pe 'BEGIN{print "["}; END{print "]\n"}' | \
perl -pe 's/},]/}]/'
```

Example above parses author, commit, date, message values. How can we parse the value of `Approved-by` which is available when a pull-request is approved.

Even the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) does not mention that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Approved-by` is not a builtin field so Git doesn't have a placeholder for it. We could use other methods to get the fields and format the output.

Suppose the `Approved-by` line looks like:

> Approved-by: Someone Nice

Here is a bash sample:

```
for commit in $(git log --pretty=%H);do
  echo -e "{\n\
    \"commit\": \"$commit\",\n\
    \"author\": \"$(git log -1 $commit --pretty=%an)\",\n\
    \"date\": \"$(git log -1 $commit --pretty=%cd)\",\n\
    \"message\": \"$(git log -1 $commit --pretty=%f)\",\n\
    \"approved-by\": \"$(git log -1 $commit --pretty=%b | grep Approved-by | awk -F ': ' '{print $NF","}' | xargs echo | sed -e 's/,$//')\"\n\
},"
done | \
perl -pe 'BEGIN{print "["}' | \
sed -e '$s/},/}]/'
```

It needs improvement to meet your real needs, especially the `\"approved-by\"` line. Basically it gets all the commit sha1 values first and then parse them to get the fields of each commit and then format the output.

Comment: Thanks ! I will test, but  I hope you consider that `Approved-By:` can be exist more than once .

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI Sorry but it's beyond my bash skills to deal with multiple `Approved-by` lines. I'll have a try.